# MySQL and PHP Row Array

Tags: php, mysql

Alright so I have an innate fear of everything MySQL

Here's my table:

```
+----+-----------------+------+
| id | name            | age  |
+----+-----------------+------+
|  1 | Timmy Mellowman |   23 |
|  2 | Jeff Johnson    |   18 |
+----+-----------------+------+
```

Here's my `PHP code` (*outside of connecting to the DB*)

```
$raw = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example") or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($raw);
echo "\n\n";
print_r($row);
```

So here's my output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => Timmy Mellowman
    [name] => Timmy Mellowman
    [2] => 23
    [age] => 23
)
```

Why is this the output? Double the name? Why is the the name set for both [1] and [name]?

And on the side is their a better way to use PHP with MySQL

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions.  As you seem to be learning how to use PHP, now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: This is defined behavior; strictly speaking, this is a "feature" of PHP, not MySQL. MySQL is returning just one copy of the values; PHP is populating the array with two styles of indexes: by numeric position and by name. You can specify which indexes are to be used (name, numeric, or both) with an additional parameter passed to the `mysql_fetch_array` function.  The default, when you don't specify, is BOTH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the **[PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)** for mysql_fetch_array:

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on
>   how result_type is defined. **By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get
>   an array with both associative and number indices.** Using MYSQL_ASSOC,
>   you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using
>   MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

So in your line `$row = mysql_fetch_array($raw);` $row receives an array that has both associative and numeric indices since that's the default. If you want only associative indices, use `$row = mysql_fetch_array($raw,MYSQL_ASSOC);` (or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`) or is you want only numeric indices, use `$row = mysql_fetch_array($raw,MYSQL_NUM);` (or `mysql_fetch_row()`).

To retrieve all your rows, use something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw)) {
    echo "<p>" . $row['id'] . " - " . $row['name'] . " - " . $row['age'] . "</p>\n";  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and great answer as I see what you mean now - but it only shows data for the first person? Shouldn't SELECT * FROM example return ALL the rows?

Comment: It does but you are only retrieving the first record. You would have to loop to retrieve them all. See example #2 from the link in my answer.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Still a bit confused, why do I need to loop and how would I do that? I've seen while statements that do this but I'm just rerunning the same command over and over and it will automatically move down a row each time?

Comment: If you look at example #2 at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php you'll see the while loop example and what that does is retrieve each row from the query, one row at a time, just as you surmised.

Comment: OH ok, yes I didn't read the link part (looked in your answer for example #2)- thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If return type not specified , Default is `mysql_fetch_array ( $raw ,MYSQL_BOTH )`
 which returns both associative and numeric indices as above.

For numeric indices use

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($raw, MYSQL_NUM)
```

For associative indices use

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

For accessing all rows use while loop

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($row, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s Age:%s", $row[0], $row[1],$row[2]);  
}
```

or if are using associative indices

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s Age:%s", $row["id"], $row["name"],$row["age"]);
}
```